# Minitest undefined method for OptionParser class

Tags: ruby, minitest

After including a module in `spec_helper`, I am running Minitest spec for a class inside that module and get this error:

```
test_0001_must be true for option name(MyGem::OptionParser::option?):
NoMethodError: undefined method `option?' for OptionParser:Class
```

I'm testing lib/options/options.rb:

```
module MyGem
  class OptionParser
    def self.option?(arg)
      arg =~ /^-{1,2}\w+$/
    end
  end
end
```

With spec/options_spec.rb:

```
describe OptionParser do
  describe "option?" do
    it "must be true for option name" do
      OptionParser.option?('--nocolor').must_equal true
    end
  end
end
```

Running the test with `MyGem::OptionParser` instead of just `OptionParser` doesn't cause errors. But similar test on `lib/script.rb` runs without errors without `MyGem::` prefix.

My file structure:

```
gem/
|-lib/
| |-options/
| | |-options.rb
| |-script.rb
|-spec/
| |-script_spec.rb
| |-options_spec.rb
| |-spec_helper.rb
|-Rakefile
```

I `include MyGem` in `spec_helper`. What have I got wrong?

Comment: Hi again, leemour. Didn't my comment in your previous question solve this? Anyway, how does your 'spec_helper' look like?

Comment: Hi, Gjaldon. I still had an issue after your comment, so I created a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minitest either already includes or auto loads Ruby's own `OptionParser`, so that presumably is taking precedence and preventing the loading of your version. Here's evidence:

```
MacbookAir1:so1 palfvin$ irb
2.0.0p247 :001 > OptionParser
NameError: uninitialized constant OptionParser
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
2.0.0p247 :002 > require 'minitest'
 => true 
2.0.0p247 :003 > OptionParser
 => OptionParser 
2.0.0p247 :004 >
```

Comment: I am not using Rails. By similar test I mean testing a method of MyGem::OtherClass in `lib/script.rb`.

Comment: You gave me a very good tip for `OptionParser` reserved name. After renaming it to `OptionsParser` the tests worked. Thanks a lot! I just don't understand, why there is a name conflict. `OptionParser` comes with Ruby http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html but I didn't find where it is required by Minitest.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that in my example where I included the module, contained classes are accessible without specifying the module prefix. Can you give an example when your statement is true?

Comment: @leemour I was off base with that comment. I still haven't managed to get my head satisfactorily around modules. Sorry for misleading you in that regard. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have exactly the same MyGem::OptionParser defined in your `script.rb` file, that is likely what is causing issues in your spec. Try using another namespace for your code in options.rb like so:

```
module MyOtherGem
  class OptionParser
    def self.option?(arg)
      arg =~ /^-{1,2}\w+$/
    end
  end
end
```

Then make sure to include it in your spec_helper or in your options_spec file.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I inadvertently downvoted your answer, particularly pathetic since mine was wrong. ;-) If you'll edit it, I'll remove the downvote.